# Codeigniter: Cannot upload files, Undefined Index

Tags: php, codeigniter, file

I cannot seem to upload files in codeigniter. I don't know if the issue lies with the `$_FILES`, when I try do `print_r($_FILES)` It displays an empty array.

Attaching the controller and the view below:

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function upload_files(){


    $this->load->library('upload');     
    $filesCount = count($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

    for($i = 0; $i < $filesCount; $i++){
        $pathToUpload="Path/to/folder";
        $folder=$id;
        $uploadPath=$this->create_dir($pathToUpload,$folder);   
        $_FILES['userFile']['name'] = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$i];
        $_FILES['userFile']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $_FILES['userFile']['size'] = $_FILES['userfile']['size'][$i];
        $config['upload_path'] = $uploadPath;
        $config['allowed_types'] = '*';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->initialize($config);
        $this->upload->do_upload('userfile');
        $this->upload->display_errors();

    }
}
```

**VIEW**

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Controller_name/upload_files" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-lg-4">Attach Documents</label>
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <input type="file" class="form-control" size="20" name="usefile[]" multiple="multiple" />
</div>
</div> 
</form>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. I cannot seem to figure out why `$_FILES` are not getting posted

Comment: Can you set $config["allowed_types"] = "*";

Comment: before checking files count use `iseet($_FILES['userfile'])` in `if statement`.

Comment: I already have added `*`

Comment: @Gaurav If I do that then there will be no error and the file will still not upload

Comment: @davidnoronha remove load library code from first line. Also check in **view** input `name="usefile"` and **controller** `$_FILES['userfile']` should be same.

Comment: I seemed to have got it working now. The for was not posting correctly. Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the code with corrections.

1. `Remove 1st $this->load->library('upload');`
2. create a duplicate of $_FILES data. `$files = $_FILES;`
3. Correct this line. `$pathToUpload="./Path/to/folder/";`
4. Correct input field name from `name="usefile[]` to `name="userFile[]`
5. Updated the view code.

**Controller Code:**

```
public function upload_files(){


    //$this->load->library('upload');     
    $filesCount = count($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
    $files = $_FILES;
    for($i = 0; $i < $filesCount; $i++){
        $pathToUpload="./Path/to/folder/";
        $folder=$id;
        $uploadPath=$this->create_dir($pathToUpload,$folder);   
        $_FILES['userFile']['name'] = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$i];
        $_FILES['userFile']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $_FILES['userFile']['size'] = $_FILES['userfile']['size'][$i];
        $config['upload_path'] = $uploadPath;
        $config['allowed_types'] = '*';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->initialize($config);
        $this->upload->do_upload('userfile');
        $this->upload->display_errors();

    }
}
```

**View File.**

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Controller_name/upload_files" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-lg-4">Attach Documents</label>
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <input type="file" class="form-control" size="20" name="usefile[]" multiple="multiple" />
<input type="hidden" name="key" value="123"/>
<input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload"/>
</div>
</div> 
</form>
```

Comment: Hey I managed to get it working. There was an issue in the method.